# How to play MP3 streams which are received by Silverlight from WCF?

Tags: wcf, silverlight-3.0, mp3, stream, audio-streaming

How to play MP3 streams in silverlight 3? (streams which are received by Silverlight from WCF)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code example for streaming music over WCF: http://www.integratedwebsystems.com/2009/04/silverlight-wcf-and-streaming-my-personal-music-repository-on-the-go/

Comment: It's so wary close actually to what I need… but in my case it's important not to store files in File System Thank you wary much for your answer.

Comment: I'm the author of that post. The example I'm showing isn't quite streaming the mp3 from WCF; rather it's pulling the playlist from WCF. I posted that back in April, so it's changed quite a bit.  

I do have a draft I'm working on that uses REST WCF to stream MP3 and the playlist into Silverlight. The key is chunking the MP3 back in small pieces so you can start playing it before you download the whole file. Since Silverlight doesn't support consuming REST WCF, I used vanilla HTTP requests against the WCF REST service, which works out pretty well. You'll just have to iron out security.